# trouble with mongoengine and geospatial query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I'm having trouble getting Mongoengine's geospatial query to work.  I've got a `User` mongoengine class with with a field called `cached.geoLoc` which is of the mongoengine type `PointField()`.  If I call

```
User.objects(cached__geoLoc__near=[100,100])
```

Then it returns answers.  But if I want to restrict the results to a limited radius and call:

```
User.objects(cached__geoLoc__near=[100,100], cached__geoLoc__max_distance=1000)
```

then I get an error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 1000`

I'm using MongoEngine version 0.8.7 and MongoDB 2.4  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm screaming bug here.

If I try this on a similar set of data with something like the following:

```python
class Geo(Document):
  loc = PointField()


result = Geo.objects(loc__near=[3,6], loc__max_distance=1000)
```

Then the resulting query issued to MongoDB is this:

```python
{ 
    "loc" : { 
        "$near" : { 
            "$geometry" : { 
                "type" : "Point", 
                "coordinates" : [ 3, 6 ] 
             }
        }, 
        "$maxDistance" : 1000
    }
}
```

With the problem being the `$maxDistance` modifier being in the **wrong** place.

The correct query form issued using the raw pymongo driver commands works fine:

```python
result = Geo._get_collection().find({
    "loc": {
        "$near": {
          "$geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [3,6]
          },
          "$maxDistance": 1000
        }
    }
}):
```

And mostly because we are issuing the `$maxDistance` modifier where it should be which is "within" the `$near` operator arguments.

File a bug. But you can use the direct syntax to get results as a work-around until there is a fix.

Comment: Ok, I will file a bug.  But for the meantime, do you know if it's possible to use the direct syntax and then construct a MongoEngine object out of the results?  Using direct syntax just returns a standard dictionary.

Comment: @J-bob Honestly, I've never tried. But the basic concept is that the "arguments" to the constructor "should" just be the same values as returned. So it should not be an issue to just pass in the "raw" object response and "cast" to the type of class that is exposed where you want access to other methods on that class. Done it in other language implementations. But more of a consultant on MongoEngine than a regular user of.

Comment: Regarding a workaround that still gets you MongoEngine objects, I figured out that I can use MongoEngine's `__raw__` argument (`User.objects(__raw__={<<raw pymongo syntax here>>}`).  This will return MongoEngine objects.